# Validating expiration of receipt of auto renewable IAP locally.

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to validate expiration of autorenewable subscription receipt locally(iOS 7). Currently I'm validating by comparing current device date with expiration date from receipt. But this logic fails if user changes the device date.

Any idea how can I solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Earlier i have spent time on this same issue, later ended up using server end. Also as per security concern you should include server end for in app purchase.